# Shopify Checkout UI Extension & Functions to Update Delivery Option

Tags: shopify, checkout

My aim is to rename a delivery option in the checkout. The title needs to be dynamic and come from the value of a field in a metaobject. This value is selected by the customer.

Metaobject name: Delivery Area

Fields:

1. Name
2. Zip code
3. Delivery time

So far I have:

1. Defined the metaobject and added some entries
2. Created a Checkout UI Extension that retrieves these delivery areas and renders a HTML Select element
3. When the delivery area is selected the shipping address zip code is updated to that of the selected delivery area zip code

What I need to do now is rename the delivery option so it picks up the delivery time value of the selected Delivery area and says something like "Express delivery in 2 hours"

I followed [this tutorial](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/checkout/delivery-shipping/delivery-customizations/getting-started) and have managed to add a Delivery Customization Function, and it is working as it should.

My question is, is there a way to link the Checkout UI Extension and the Function so that the Function knows when the delivery area has been selected, can pick up the delivery time value and then update the delivery option?

Here is my Checkout UI Extension:

```
import {
  extension,
  Select
} from '@shopify/ui-extensions/checkout';

export default extension('purchase.checkout.delivery-address.render-after', (root, api) => {
  const state = {
    deliveryArea: {
      name: null,
      zipCode: null
    }
  };

  api.query(
    `query ($type: String!, $first: Int!) {
      metaobjects(type: $type, first: $first) {
        nodes {
          name: field(key: "name") {
            value
          }
          zipCode: field (key: "zip_code") {
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }`,
    {
      variables: {
        type: 'delivery_area',
        first: 250
      }
    }
  )
  .then(({ data }) => {

    // Get & Set initial value in state
    const firstOption = data.metaobjects.nodes[0];

    state.deliveryArea = {
      name: firstOption.name.value,
      zipCode: firstOption.zipCode.value
    }

    updateAddressZipCode();

    // Build object for new Select element options
    const selectOptions = buildOptions(data.metaobjects.nodes);

    const select = root.createComponent(Select, {
      label: 'Choose your area',
      options: selectOptions,
      value: null,
      onChange: onSelectChange,
    });

    root.appendChild(select);
  })
  .catch(console.error);

  async function onSelectChange(selected) {
    const selectedValues = selected.split('|');

    state.deliveryArea = {
      name: selectedValues[0],
      zipCode: selectedValues[1]
    }
  
    await api.applyAttributeChange({
      key: 'delivery_area',
      type: 'updateAttribute',
      value: selectedValues[0],
    });

    updateAddressZipCode();
  }

  async function updateAddressZipCode() {
    const result = await api.applyShippingAddressChange({
      type: 'updateShippingAddress',
      address: {
        zip: state.deliveryArea.zipCode
      }
    });
  }
});

function buildOptions(data) {
  return data.map((item) => {
    return {
      value: `${item.name.value}|${item.zipCode.value}`,
      label: item.name.value
    }
  });
}
```

My Function is exactly the same as it is in the tutorial posted above.